# How to deploy via FTP a website using BitBucket Pipelines

Tags: bitbucket, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, bitbucket-pipelines

I tried many times to execute a Continuous Integration via BitBucket Pipeline (beta). For the moment I need a very simple task, just update my remote server when a push is made on repository (In the past I used for this purpose CodeShip with a very similar syntax).

In Pipelines is necessary to set up a file called `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` which contains several rows to differentiate between branches, etc. but the main instruction is:

```
- lftp -c "open -u $FTP_USER,$FTP_PASSWORD ftp.mydomain.com; set ssl:verify-certificate no; mirror -Rne /opt/atlassian/bitbucketci/agent/build /clone/ /public_html/dev"
```

Unfortunately it does not run correctly because it failed (apparently with infinite loop and new attempts).

I tried to discuss this topic with Support but I did not recieve any useful help and in the final message, they simply suggested me other resources.

Maybe, is there anybody that set up succesfully a similar things?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If its just a git push you want, you could try this.

```
image: samueldebruyn/debian-git

pipelines:
    default:
      - step:
          script:
            - echo "Pipeline Init"
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
            - echo "'_$(git status -uno --porcelain | wc -l)_'"
            - git status -uno --porcelain
            - echo "Initiating Push site:Source."
            - git config git-ftp.syncroot Source/
            - git ftp init --user $Username --passwd $Pwd ftp://domain.com/public_html/
```

Once you have done the first push (init), change the code `git ftp init` to `git ftp push`

Comment: If you also need to deploy untracked files (such as those generated by your build process) see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55452770/195835).

Comment: Does not work in 2022, 404 errors in apt-get step. Presumably the image is out of date

Comment: Fixed in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/replete/bd3f0cf5a0c6e54d78a3af160812677b