# Push a folder from Bitbucket repo to public server using Pipelines

Tags: angular, ftp, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have pipelines enabled in my Bitbucket repository and I need to run Angular 2 build and deploy the dist folder (which gets created after the build command is executed) in my server after every build.

I have following in my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file:

```
image: node:4.6.0

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - npm install
          - npm run build:prod
```

I found this code snippet on the Internet:

```
- apt-get update
- apt-get -qq install git-ftp
- git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://123.456.789.123/timount/angular_app
```

I use a pem file to login to my server through the SSH client. So is the above code snippet useful? If not, how can I use the pem file in the above command?

To make it more clear, `npm run build:prod` command actually creates the dist folder, which needs to be deployed on the server at the above location. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hey! Were you able to achieve this? I’m trying to do the same. Upload to my server my dist folder

Answer (score 5):

## 1. Write this in bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```
image: node:8.7.0
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Installation
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install
    - step:
        name: Building
        script:
          - npm install -g @angular/cli #need to install angular-cli to make build
          - npm run build --aot
    - step:
        name: Deployment
        script:
          - apt-get update
          - apt-get install ncftp
          - ncftpput -v -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" -R $FTP_HOST $FTP_SITE_ROOT dist/*
          - echo Finished uploading /dist files to $FTP_HOST$FTP_SITE_ROOT
```

## 2. Configure your bitbucket environment variables

[image]

Comment: I've the same solution but `ncftpput` command not working me. I get only error `Remote host has closed the connection.` and then `ncftpput: cannot open frp.server.com: remote host closed control connection.`

When I try to debug my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` on local Docker container all works good. Any idea please?

Answer (score 2):

### Not the answer

I don't think Git FTP is what you want here. If you look at [their website](https://git-ftp.github.io/) the reason its a product at all is to only deploy files that changed. My suspicion is that your `dist` folder will be recreated in its entirety each time you build. Even if that's not the case, they state:

> It keeps track of the uploaded files by storing the commit id in a log
>   file on the server. It uses Git to determine which local files have
>   changed.

The Bitbucket Pipelines instances are ephemeral, so there's nowhere to store the log. That undermines the motivation for using `git-ftp` at all. I suppose you could push the log somewhere and retrieve it, but I would be surprised if that were worth your time.

### Answer

I don't think there's anything particularly special about what you're trying to do - Angular and Git just happen to be involved, but you're just trying to move a folder from one machine to another. There are tons of software products that would be available to help you with that, but `scp`, which stands for Secure Copy, is one of the more popular ones which is included in many Linux distributions (what Docker container are you building off?). You can see numerous examples [here](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php), but essentially I think what you want to do comes down to:

`scp -i /path/to/your/.pemkey -r /copy/from/path user@server:/copy/to/path`

(Example taken from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22985300/4970406))

Note that you'll have to make sure the server you're going to is publicly accessible, otherwise there's no way to route from the Pipelines build to the target computer (so far as I know)

Comment: Thank you for clearing out the issue with "git-ftp" and the dist folder. Do you know any other way to deploy to FTP in a way that it keeps track of the changes already on the server? I don't want to upload all of my files on each deploys and I want old files to be removed from the server.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in [this Github thread](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/issues/46#issuecomment-478519524), while `git-ftp` is designed to only deploy tracked file changes, it is actually possible to deploy your entire `dist` folder on every commit, even if these files are untracked.

You first need to create a file called `.git-ftp-include` in the root of your repo, and add a single line with the path to your dist folder, ensuring you add `!` to the start of the line:

```
!.vuepress/dist/
```

Then run the following command:

```sh
git ftp push --all --syncroot .vuepress/dist/
```

The `--all` uploads ALL your files (even unchanged ones), while `--syncroot` only uploads the files within the specified folder (uploading them to the root folder).